# Interface capacitive digitizer via i2c

Tags: pi-2, i2c, touchscreen

Hi Guys I need help interfacing a capacitive digitizer with the rpi2.
The digitizer has a goodix gt9137 touch controller and the drivers are in the Linux kernel.After I hook it up what do I do?Will it just work or am I missing something?

I've attached the pin out of the digitizer.Please help me !!!
Awaiting your replies.[image]

Thanks.